# a.s convergence is implied convergence in probability and a.s. convergence of a subsequence

Tags: probability-theory

This is Exercise 7.40 from Resnick's A Probability Path.

Suppose $\left\{X_{n}, n \geq 1\right\}$ are independent and set $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$. Then $S_{n} / n \rightarrow$ 0 almost surely iff the following two conditions hold:
(a) $S_{n} / n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} 0$,
(b) $S_{2^{n}} / 2^{n} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Would someone provide a hint or a solution?